# Download a webpage with everything it needs in a dedicated directory, by browser in command line?

Tags: ubuntu, google-chrome, firefox, download

To download a webpage ( its html file and other files needed by it),
`wget` seems to mirror the directory structure of the files of the webpage on the website server

When in a web browser (e.g. Firefox or Chrome), by hitting Ctrl-s, we creates a html file and a directory named something like `..._files` which contains all needed    files by the webpage, and change the links to the needed files in the html file accordingly.

I wonder if the second approach can be done in command line by some program? Can `wget` do that? Can Firefox or Chrome be used from command line?

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

From `man wget`:

```
   -p
   --page-requisites
       This option causes Wget to download all the files that are necessary to
       properly display a given HTML page.  This includes such things as inlined
       images, sounds, and referenced stylesheets.

    -k
   --convert-links
       After the download is complete, convert the links in the document to make
       them suitable for local viewing.  This affects not only the visible
       hyperlinks, but any part of the document that links to external content,
       such as embedded images, links to style sheets, hyperlinks to non-HTML
       content, etc.
```